# Passenger not working for location block inside server block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, nginx, passenger

I have Passenger configured on my nginx server to serve a Rails app from a specific domain.

I need a certain path (`/works`) on my app not to time out after 60s because it takes a while for me to upload files and I suspect the timeout is firing too early. I wanted to use [`proxy_connect_timeout`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_connect_timeout) to solve the issue.

I tried to use a location block specific to that path in order to increase the timeout, but it causes every request for `/works` (or any subpath) to result in a 404.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myserver.com;
    root /path/to/my/app/public;
    passenger_enabled on;

    location /works {
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
    }
}
```

This is the entry in `error.log`:

> 2014/02/10 04:30:31 [error] 9579#0: *4 "/path/to/my/app/public/works/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 0.0.0.0, server: myserver.com, request: "GET /works/ HTTP/1.1", host: "myserver.com"

From what I can glean from that entry, it seems to look into public as if it didn't know it should pass the request to Rails. I also tried enabling passenger from that location block but with no luck.

---

How do I get this to work? Is there also a way to make the location block only act on `/works` and not on any subpath (e.g. `/works/1`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must re-specify `passenger_enabled` in each location block.

From the [Phusion Passenger users guide:](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_passenger_enabled_lt_on_off_gt)

> When using `location` blocks, you must re-specify `passenger_enabled` in each `location` block that you want to enable Phusion Passenger. This is because each `location` block has `passenger_enabled` turned off by default.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this again. I thought I had already tried it and it wasn't working, but maybe I just did something wrong.